# Azure Function stopped without any changes

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

Since Monday (yesterday; 09/08) my AF stopped working. I haven't made any changes.
Instead of immediate result on HTTPTrigger function (less than 1sec) it's working 300sec (5min) and then the error can be found in Application Insights:

```
Message:
Exception while executing function: Functions.MetricsHttpStart Did not find any initialized language workers    

Exception type: 
System.InvalidOperationException
    
Failed method: 
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcFunctionInvocationDispatcherLoadBalancer.GetLanguageWorkerChannel

Assembly:
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

SDK version: 
azurefunctions: 3.1.4.0
```

I'm aware of similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66146472/azure-function-suddenly-stopped-working-on-azure)
Also [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4974)

I've tried to redeploy, change runtime version, etc. and nothing helped. What am I missing?

AF properties/settings:

1. Azure Function (Durable)
2. Consumption plan Y1
3. Linux
4. FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME: python
5. FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION: ~3 (which is `3.1.4.0` at this moment)
6. python code
7. requirements.txt updated today (see below)
8. linuxFxVersion: "Python|3.8"

```
requirements.txt:
azure-functions==1.7.2
pandas==1.3.1
pyodbc==4.0.31
openpyxl==3.0.7
azure-storage-blob==12.8.1
azure-functions-durable==1.0.3
typing==3.7.4.3
azure-identity==1.6.0
azure-keyvault-secrets==4.3.0
numpy==1.21.1
```

```
host.json:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)"
  }
}
```

Comment: I recommend you open an issue on github for this one..

Comment: [HERE](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/2010) it is